# How to set Permissions to write into a .env.local.php file

Tags: php, database, laravel, file-permissions, configuration-files

I am writing a setup/quickstart page for my laravel application that allows the user to setup their DB connections. I would like to allow PHP to write a .env.local.php file onto the server, but I'm not sure where to put it, and how to get the permissions to be able to write this file. I would like to avoid setting the entire application to 777 as that probably isn't a good idea, but I'm not sure what I should set it to. Also, what should I set it to after the .env.local.php file has been written?

Comment: Either the file owner or group must be set to the same user running the web server, or you can use something like suPHP. suPHP executes php scripts with the permission of the user owning them. http://www.suphp.org

Comment: figure out what account your webserver is running under (e.g. www-data, nobody, etc...) and grant that account rights to your file.

Comment: How would I make this so that anyone could download the software and install it on their own servers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually you need the webserver to have write access to that file, so you can change the group to the one your webserver belongs to:

```
chown yourusername:www-data .env.local.php
```

And make it writable for user and group:

```
chmod 660 .env.local.php
```